# Сумма элементов списка после первого отрицательного элемента

Tags: python, list

Условие: Пользователь вводит список из 15 элементов типа int
spisok = [1,2,3,4,-5,10,20,22,30,-14,15,17,16,13,21]
И программа должна:
Найти индекс минимального элемента списка и найти сумму всех элементов списка после первого отрицательного числа. (То есть после (-5) найти сумму всех остальных элементов)

Answer (score 0):

получить список чисел можно так:

```
arr = list(map(int, input()))
```

все остальное - примитивный алгоритм с использованием `for`

> Найти индекс минимального элемента списка

1. пройти по всем элементам массива и найти минимальный и соответствующий ему индекс

> найти сумму всех элементов списка после первого отрицательного числа

1. дойти до первого отрицательного числа
2. сделать срез массива от текущего индекса
3. использовать функцию `sum()`

P.S.

а вообще нехорошо такие вопросы в воскресенье спрашивать - это навевает грустные мысли об образовании и желании учиться :)

Comment: вот первый пункт я и не могу сделать мне бы код хотя бы этого первого пункта
дойти до первого отрицательного числа

Comment: @lxrd придётся вооружиться учебником и написать код самостоятельно. Ничего сверхсложного тут нет.

Comment: я же написал - используйте команду `for`, что мешает теперь прочитать о команде, иначе для такой задачи придётся привести весь код целиком, т.е. полностью решить задачу для вас

Comment: я прекрасно знаю что нужен цикл for, для меня составляет небольшую проблему выполнить первый пункт, я дохожу до 
for i in range(len(0, spisok)):
    if i<0:
и дальше стопорюсь

Comment: а попробуйте без кода пока написать алгоритм в виде текста действий и вы имеете в виду второй пункт - про отрицательные числа?

Comment: Так то я понимаю что должна делать программа и какой пункт сначала и тд, я просто не мог в виде самого кода присвоить первый отрицательный к новой переменной, в итоге получилось, ступор был
x = None
for i in spisok:
 if i<0:
  x = i
  break

Comment: так и рассмотрите 2 случая - элемент `[0]` уже отрицательный и вам надо подсчитать сумму `arr[1:]` иначе ищите отрицательный элемент, делайте срез от следующей позиции, вычисляйте сумму и выходите из цикла